# How to download punkt tokenizer in nltk?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I installed the NLTK library using

```
pip install nltk
```

and while using the lib

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize 
sent_tokenize(text)
```

I am getting this error

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle

  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\adars/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\adars\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\adars\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\share\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\adars\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\adars\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - ''
```

So in order to solve this error i tried

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

but then i am unable to download this package because everytime i run this i get error that says

```
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A
[nltk_data]     connection attempt failed because the connected party
[nltk_data]     did not properly respond after a period of time, or
[nltk_data]     established connection failed because connected host
[nltk_data]     has failed to respond>
```

please help me out here

Comment: Add [this](https://github.com/delip/PyTorchNLPBook/issues/14#issuecomment-1057151683) in your script and then do `nltk.download('punkt')`. See if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely happening due to a network issue. You can try either of the following solutions:

**1.** Add the following in your script:

```
import nltk
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download('punkt')
```

**2.** If the above solution doesn't help, then:

- Manually download `'punkt'` from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.zip).
- Unzip the file and then go to `'C:/Users/adars/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/lib/'` where you need to create a folder named `nltk_data`.
- Under `nltk_data`, create another folder named `tokenizers` and place the extracted folder `punkt` there so that you get a new directory `tokenizers/punkt` which would contain all the `.pickle` files.
- Once that's done, you don't need to do `nltk.download('punkt')`
  again, just directly run your code.

Comment: the first solution is not working and the link is not opening in the second solution

Comment: The link contains the `.zip` file, it won't open any page for you. If you'd like to access the page, then go [here](https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) and find `'punkt'` package zip file yourself.

Comment: on clicking this link 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.zip 

it shows 
raw.githubusercontent.com took too long to respond

Comment: I think it's your network that's blocking you from accessing this page which is [happening](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/3092) to some users from specific geolocation . You can perhaps try using [VPN](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/3092#issuecomment-1377184138) or follow [this](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/3092#issuecomment-1398658093) to use `wget` on powershell (as your OS is windows) to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

1. just open any prompt or anaconda prompt & activate env in which your running the script
2. type python
3. press enter
4. execute `import nltk`
5. `nltk.download('punkt')`

onced downloaded you can continue with your code ide

Comment: i am not using any env running it in my cmd and this is the result

Comment: C:\Users\adars>python
Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('punkt')
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A
[nltk_data]     connection attempt failed because the connected party
[nltk_data]     did not properly respond after a period of time, or
[nltk_data]     established connection failed because connected host
[nltk_data]     has failed to respond>
False

Comment: so, you can follow the same steps without activating the env .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: tried it still shows the same error